# .Net Kendo HtmlHelper Ajax MultiSelect Initial Values

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an Kendo MultiSelect which uses ajax to grab the select menu potential values from a database table that is not directly related to the model.

MultiSelect:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()  
    .Name("ContactTags")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("TagId")
    .Placeholder("Please select a tag")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetTags", "ContactTag");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

The above code with render the Select Menu and post the data back to the controller where I can parse it and send it to the database. That all works when creating a new tag. The problem arises when there are already existing tags on an entity. How do I make Kendo get the existing tags and mark them as selected in the Multiselect menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a list of the selected items in the controller action that calls this view and it to your Model (ViewModel).

Then add a [.Value()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/multiselect/overview#pre-select-values-on-initial-load) clause to the widget:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()  
    .Name("ContactTags")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("TagId")
    .Placeholder("Please select a tag")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Value(Model.SelectedTags)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetTags", "ContactTag");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```